# Extras are null

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to send data from Activity A to B.
This is the code in A (Working fine):

```
    public void sendToFavorites(Context context){
        String vID,vThumbnail,vTitle;
        vID = sendResult.getId().getVideoId();
        vThumbnail = sendResult.getSnippet().getThumbnails().getMedium().getUrl();
        vTitle = sendResult.getSnippet().getTitle();
        fav = new Intent(context,Favorites.class);
        fav.putExtra("title",vTitle);
        fav.putExtra("thumbnail",vThumbnail);
        fav.putExtra("id",vID);
}
```

But the extras in Activity B says null:

```
  Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras(); //extras: null
```

How can I fix it?

Comment: other code won't help here. The problem is only here.

Comment: @Arash is right, we need more code. For instance are you actually triggering this activity using startActivity(fav) ? Or is activity some other activity that is unaware of intents created in A ?

Comment: @JohnDoe, you keep posting the same question over and over. You have to use the same **Intent** object you are filling up to start the Activity. You call startActivity on a new instance, you'll get always null extras

Comment: @Blackbelt Sorry for this over and over posting, but I can't figure out how to do it. Okay, I know I should start the activity right after, but it also gives me problems.

Comment: it would be more helpful if you included the error you are getting

Comment: @Blackbelt this is the error: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.app.ActivityThread$ApplicationThread android.app.ActivityThread.getApplicationThread()' on a null object reference

Comment: use a Toast to check if you vTitle, vThumbnail and vID are null, also use a if, if(extras!=null){extras.getString} check this and tell us, if it works

Comment: as usual, edit your question, and post the whole stacktrace

Comment: @CarlosCarrizales when I send them, they are not null, when im trying to get them, the extras are null .

Comment: @Blackbelt I don't have log, only if I put breakpoint, I get this line and this line only.

Comment: Where in your code is ` Bundle extras = getIntent().getExtras();`? And take the suggestions of others and do it the right way and edit to include how it isn't working/crashing.instead of posting new (duplicate) questions.With less information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can only get extras as bundle, if you use below overload

```
intent.putExtras(Bundle extras);
```

In your case, you have to use

```
getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
or 
getIntent().getIntExtra("title",defaultvalue);
```

based on your extra datatype

Comment: thanks, I'm trying it now, but how can I add all my 3 variables?

Comment: you are already passing 3 variables, leave it that way. but in second activity you have to use 
       getIntent().getStringExtra("title");
        getIntent().getStringExtra("thumbnail");
        getIntent().getStringExtra("id");